# How do I suppress jQuery "undefined" Message

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code which displays the warning "undefined" until an option is selected in the drop-down. Is there a way to stop this message appearing?

```
<select id="currency" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Currency</option>
    <option value="1,$">USD</option>
    <option value="1,£">GBP</option>
</select>

<p><span id='symbol1'></span>0.00</p>

<script>

   $(document).ready(currencyFunction);
   document.getElementById("currency").addEventListener("change", currencyFunction);

   function currencyFunction() {

       select=document.getElementById('currency').value.split(',');

       display = select[1];

       document.getElementById("symbol1").innerHTML = display;
   }

</script>
```

Comment: What is the undefined error? second, maybe you need to add `var` to select and display

Comment: Why do you need to run `currencyFunction` on document ready? It's trying to parse your default value, which is `""`, and failing when you try to get the second value from it.

Comment: @EvanKnowles That was super simple - thanks!

Comment: @JohnHiggins, I have explained this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `currencyFunction` in document.ready event.

You are getting `undefined` error because you are calling `currencyFunction` when document is ready and the function is trying to access value of the dropdown. But when the page is just got ready, dropdown will have empty value selected. So its giving that error.

But if you want to supress the error anyhow, then do like this:

```
   function currencyFunction() {
     if(document.getElementById('currency').value != '')
     {
       select=document.getElementById('currency').value.split(',');

       display = select[1];

       document.getElementById("symbol1").innerHTML = display;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution than javascript syntax:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#currency', function() {
     $("#symbol1").html($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="currency" required>
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Currency</option>
    <option value="$">USD</option>
    <option value="£">GBP</option>
</select>

<p><span id='symbol1'></span>0.00</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function as soon as the page loads as the function is called without selecting any options you are getting the value as undefined, Please check the code below, I've made some changes :

```js
   function currencyFunction() {
       select=document.getElementById('currency').value.split(',');

       display = select[1];

       document.getElementById("symbol1").innerHTML = display;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="currency" required onchange="currencyFunction()">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Currency</option>
    <option value="1,$">USD</option>
    <option value="1,£">GBP</option>
</select>

<p><span id='symbol1'></span>0.00</p>
```

Call the function by using `onchange` event inside the select tag, this will call the function only when the select options are changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/foqced1v/1/)**,

**HTML**

```
<select id="currency" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled>Select Currency</option>
  <option value="1,$">USD</option>
  <option value="1,£">GBP</option>
</select>

<p><span id='symbol1'></span>0.00</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select').on('change', function() {
     var valueSelected = this.value.split(',');
     console.log(valueSelected[1]);
     var temp = $("#symbol1").text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
     $("#symbol1").html(valueSelected[1]+" "+temp);
   });
});
```